# Opentaps 1.5M3 not available to download

Tags: multi-tenant, ofbiz, opentaps

I have started using opentaps and want to set up this in multi-tenant mode.
In opentaps-1.5, create-tenant target is not available so we can not create tenant dynamically.

After googling a lot, i found latest ofbiz provide this functionality
I want to this in opentaps, but not able to download 1.5M3.

Can any one help me over this?

Answer (score 1):

Opentaps is an OFBiz fork, they are are not in synch for a long time now. To use the latest OFBiz features and profit from the community work I suggest to switch to standard OFBiz.

If you need certain features in standard OFBiz which are missing, please feel free to submit a [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OFBIZ/) issue.

Comment: actually my problem is i want to set up opentaps in multi-tenant mode where i can create tenant dynamically with ant target like we are dong in latest ofbiz which is not available in opentaps.I followed all docs mentioned for opentaps multi-tenant. I can create tenant with xml files but this is not my requirement.So can you help me over this?

Comment: If you still want to stick with Operntaps, why not take the ant targets from standard OFBiz and put them in the Opentaps ant scripts?

Comment: I have just started development in ofbiz,I tried to integrate opentaps feature with ofbiz through moving components into hot-deploy folder but that is not working can you suggest some example for doing this?

Comment: I guess this will not work. The two systems are not compatible and for a beginner this would be a huge tasks. 

For stackoverflow you would have to ask more concrete questions to get help.

Comment: I am integrating UPS API in opentaps, they upgraded their TLS version to 1.2 and told me to upgrade your java. I changed my JAVA_HOME to 1.7 but still there is an error says protocol_version mismatch. Also how do i upgrade internal javac compiler to 1.5 right now it is set to 1.5 and 1.6 in opentaps coonfiguration files